# Different while debuging and executing code

Tags: c#

Something weird is happening with some values in a list. I have `object` which has property `List<IEmployers>`

I have this code

```
IList<IPayroll> tmpPayrolls = incomeTypesPayrolls[incomeType]
                        .Where(p => p.Employee.EmployeeID == grPayrolls.Employee.EmployeeID).ToList();
var tempEmployers = tmpPayrolls.FirstOrDefault() != null ? tmpPayrolls.FirstOrDefault().Employers : null;
```

When I click on `tmpPayrolls` there is one item in it and it has 1 `Employer`
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxnko.jpg)
When I try to get it's employers my object `tempEmployers` has no employers
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxnEf.png)

Comment: [Heisenbug](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)

Comment: FYI you can do `tmpPayrolls.FirstOrDefault()?.Employers` instead.

Comment: Yeah you are correct but we are using .Net Framework 4.0